# What does "staged" mean in the context of dictionary download?

Tags: google-play-store, gboard, dictionary

[image]

Google search can't answer my question
What does staged mean?
Sorry I'm a pretty new to the tech thing

Answer (score 0):

My *guess* is that it refers to a [staged rollout](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en), which means that it is available only to a few users not all. Since you are unable to download, you are being told that the dictionary is available but not yet for you (or people in your region)